# integral with function Gamma

Tags: calculus, integration

In the article  *The Annals of Statistics Vol 18 March 1990, Natural exponential families with cubic variance functions*, he is shown with a probabilistic method that $$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^{x+p-1}e^{-x}}{\Gamma(x+p+1)}dx=\frac{1}{p}.$$

I am looking for a proof of analysis

Comment: Perhaps you might be able to use the integral representation $$\frac1{\Gamma(z)}=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(c+it)^{-z}e^{c+it}dt$$ for $z\in\Bbb C$ and any real $c>0$, where the integral is along the real line $t\in\Bbb R$.

Comment: @clathratus I doubt we'll find anything concrete

Comment: are you sure that the result is correct? the $x^{x+p-1}$ is really troublesome looking

Comment: clathratus   it's correct

Comment: Could you include the proof that was supplied?

Comment: The Annals of Statistics Vol 18 March 1990, Natural exponential families with cubic variance functions pages 1-37. proposition 5.5 page 27