# Gamma-Distribution-like integral

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, gamma-function, complex-integration

I have numerically checked this result and although it doesn't hold to a significant number of decimal places I believe this result is true:

$$\Large \int_0^\infty \frac{x^x e^{-x}}{\Gamma(x+2)}\text{d}x = 1$$

This only vaguely resembles a Gamma Distribution, so I do not see how to explain it using distributions.

I would imagine complex analysis is the way to go with such an integral but I have no idea where to even begin.

I tried using Stirling's (Convergent) Approximation but given how complicated the product expansion is in terms of exponentiated inverted rising factorials, I don't think that is a very nice method.

Comment: The original post is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3453788/515527) in case you wonder how this appeared.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $\gamma$ be Hankle's contour. It is well-known that:
$$\dfrac{1}{\Gamma(z)}=\dfrac{i}{2\pi}\int_{\gamma}(-t)^{-z}e^{-t}{\rm d}t$$
STEP 1: Considering the integral:
\begin{align*}
J(a)& =\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^xe^{-ax}}{\Gamma(x+1)}{\rm d}x\\
& =\dfrac{i}{2\pi}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-ax}{\rm d}x\int_{\gamma}(-t)^{-x-1}e^{-tx}{\rm d}t\\
& =-\dfrac{i}{2\pi}\int_{\gamma}\dfrac{{\rm d}t}{t(a+t+\log(-t))}\\
& =-\dfrac{1}{1+W_{-1}(-e^{-a})},
\end{align*}
where $W_{-1}(z)$ is Lambert W function. The last equation is right due to residue theorem.

STEP 2: Hence \begin{align*}
I & = e\int_{0}^{\infty}{\rm d}x\int_{1}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^xe^{-a(1+x)}}{\Gamma(1+x)}{\rm d}a\\
& =e\int_1^{\infty}e^{-a}J(a){\rm d}a\\
& =-e\int_1^{\infty}\dfrac{e^{-a}}{1+W_{-1}(-e^{-a})}{\rm d}a\\
& =-e\int_0^{-1/e}\dfrac{{\rm d}t}{1+W_{-1}(t)}\\
& =e\int_{-\infty}^{-1}e^W_{-1}{\rm d}W=1
\end{align*}
The last equation is right due to $W'_{-1}(z)(1+W_{-1}(z))e^{W_{-1}(z)}=1.$

Corollary：$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^{x+p-1}e^{-x}}{\Gamma(x+p+1)}dx=\frac{1}{p}.$$
[Here](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aos/1176347491) Proposition 5.5 at Page 27

The same question has been discussed on MathOverflow, see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/283662/integral-involving-gamma-function-density-of-kendall-ressel-family-of-distribut)

Comment: $\int_0^{\infty } \frac{x^x \exp (-a x)}{\Gamma (x+1)} \, dx=-\frac{1}{1+W(-\exp
   (-a))}$ is not true,I checked numerically ?

Comment: @Mariusz Iwaniuk, I believe one has been a little sloppy here. When dealing with the Lambert W function one should always specify which branch of the function one is dealing with. In this case it is the $k = -1$ branch. Thus $$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^x e^{-ax}}{\Gamma (x + 1)} \, dx = -\frac{1}{1 + \operatorname{W}_{-1} (-e^{-a})}$$ for $a > 1$.

Comment: Sorry @Mariusz Iwaniuk, I meant to say the solver has been a little sloppy in not specifying which branch of the Lambert W function they were considering, not you.

Comment: @Mariusz Iwaniuk Sorry for my fault. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for correcting an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot access the paper in the linked closed question.

Considering your problem, let us write
$$I=\int_{0}^\infty \frac{x^x e^{-x}}{\Gamma(x+2)}\,dx=\int_0^{10^k} \frac{x^x e^{-x}}{\Gamma(x+2)}\,dx+\int_{10^k}^\infty \frac{x^x e^{-x}}{\Gamma(x+2)}\,dx=I_{1k}+I_{2k}$$
$I_{1k}$ would be computed numerically.

Concerning the second one, for large value of $10^k=p$, using Stirling approximation and continuing with Taylor series, we have
$$\frac{x^x e^{-x}}{\Gamma(x+2)}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi x^3}} \left(1-\frac{13}{12 x}+\frac{313}{288 x^2}-\frac{56201}{51840
   x^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^4}\right)\right)$$ from which
$$\int_p^\infty\frac{x^x e^{-x}}{\Gamma(x+2)}\,dx=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi\,p }} \left(1-\frac{13}{36 p}+\frac{313}{1440 p^2}-\frac{56201}{362880
   p^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^4}\right) \right)$$ Now, computing for a few values of $k$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 k & I_{1k} & I_{2k} & I_{1k}+ I_{2k} \\
 1 & 0.75628589652513868756 & 0.24371129421828760677 & 0.99999719074342629434 \\
 2 & 0.92049794687117372168 & 0.07950205303351501669 & 0.99999999990468873837 \\
 3 & 0.97477778061127925239 & 0.02522221938871771364 & 0.99999999999999696603 \\
 4 & 0.99202144249960996668 & 0.00797855750039003538 & 1.00000000000000000206 \\
 5 & 0.99747687658923688302 & 0.00252312341076311767 & 1.00000000000000000069 \\
 6 & 0.99920211572732194172 & 0.00079788427267805849 & 1.00000000000000000022
\end{array}
\right)$$